# How to merge faces without creating new shapes

Tags: modeling, faces, sculpting

I'm in the process of learning how to create models with Blender.

Right now I'm trying to create a circle with a hole in the middle, for that i create a simple circle and then I extrude with this result:

[image]

I then proceed to select all the faces and I press `F`.

I can do this but at the last face this happens

[image]

Why this happens and how con I avoid it? The goal is to have a ring with only one face, export it to fbx and import in Unreal Engine.

For reference, this is the end result I'm aiming for:

[image]

I've also tried to do the same on a vertical axis and this happens (images before and after some merges):

[image]
[image]

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do, if you try to fill the hole, you need to select the inner circle only, otherwise you will also create a face inside the outer edge loop that will overlay on all the other faces

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The goal is a get a 2D ring with only one circular face. I try to achieve this by merging the single faces that the extrusion creates one by one, but with the last one, Blender automatically create one face inside the inner ring. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to create. Can u add an image of the thing that you are trying to model.

Comment: I think he's trying to create a ring (therefore keep the hole), then merge all the faces of the ring, except you need to keep at least 2 faces in the ring if you don't want to fill the inner circle: Blender can fill a closed ngons shape but is not supposed to fill the space between ngons, I'm trying to find the words to make myself clear...

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I'm trying to achieve: a single ngon with a hole in the middle. I've added another image (the third one) in which I've edited out the lines of the last remaining face via photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create 2 unfilled circles and press F, they will fill independently, Blender won’t fill the gap between them. If you put the small circle inside the big one, it’s the exact same situation, the same thing will happen.

[image]
[image]

This explains what’s happening with your ring, if you delete all the faces within the ring, Blender can’t guess the 2 circles are supposed to be linked to each other, it will fill both the outer and the inner circle but won’t fill the gap between them.

To do so you need to create at least 2 edges between the outer and the inner circle , then in *Edge Select* mode select each face and fill.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Note that by doing this you will end up with n-gons (faces with more than 4 vertices), depending on what you want to do with the model, this might create more problems down the line. Try to stay with quad topology if you can.